# Guzzle Error - JSON parameters. Trying to create a Marketo Token

Tags: php, guzzle, marketo

Using Guzzle 6.3, PHP7.2 and I'mm trying to create a Marketo Token.

```
$response = $this->client->post(
    '/rest/asset/v1/folder/' . $this->folder . '/tokens.json',
    [
        'query' => ['access_token' => $this->getToken()],
        'json' => [
            'folderType' => $this->folderType,
            'type'       => 'text',
            'name'       => request()->query('title'),
            'value'      => 'summary',
        ]
    ]);
```

Getting this response back

```
array:3 [▼
  "success" => false
  "errors" => array:4 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▼
      "message" => "name cannot be null."
      "code" => "701"
    ]
    1 => array:2 [▼
      "message" => "type cannot be null."
      "code" => "701"
    ]
    2 => array:2 [▼
      "message" => "Token type is either null, blank or invalid. Please refer to the documentation for valid token types."
      "code" => "701"
    ]
    3 => array:2 [▼
      "message" => "value cannot be null."
      "code" => "701"
    ]
  ]
  "requestId" => "fba7#1624f4299f0"
]
```

Clearly I'm calling it incorrectly, but according to the Guzzle docs it should be right?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that this API doesn't accept JSON parameters, it's expecting a form, so you have to use `form_params` instead of `json`